# HTML parsing using beautiful soup gives structure different to website

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I view this link https://www.cftc.gov/sites/default/files/files/dea/cotarchives/2015/futures/financial_lf061615.htm the text is displayed in a clear way. However when I try to parse the page using beautiful soup I am outputting something which doesn't look the same - it is all messed up. Here is the code

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = urllib.request.Request('https://www.cftc.gov/sites/default/files/files/dea/cotarchives/2015/futures/financial_lf061615.htm')
htm = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htm,'html.parser')
text = soup.get_text()
print(text)
```

The desired ouput would look like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traders in Financial Futures - Futures Only Positions as of June 16, 2015                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              Dealer            :           Asset Manager/       :            Leveraged           :              Other             :     Nonreportable    :
           Intermediary         :           Institutional        :              Funds             :           Reportables          :       Positions      :
    Long  :   Short  : Spreading:    Long  :   Short  : Spreading:    Long  :   Short  : Spreading:    Long  :   Short  : Spreading:    Long  :   Short   :
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOW JONES UBS EXCESS RETURN - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE   ($100 X INDEX)                               
CFTC Code #221602                                                    Open Interest is    19,721
Positions
        97      2,934          0      8,941      1,574        973      6,490     11,975      1,694      1,372        539          0        154         32

Changes from:       June 9, 2015                                     Total Change is:     3,505
        48          0          0      2,013      1,141         70        447      1,369        923        -64          0          0         68          2

Percent of Open Interest Represented by Each Category of Trader
       0.5       14.9        0.0       45.3        8.0        4.9       32.9       60.7        8.6        7.0        2.7        0.0        0.8        0.2

Number of Traders in Each Category                                    Total Traders:        31 
         .          .          0          5          .          .          6          9          .          5          .          0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After viewing the page source it is not clear to me how a new line is being distingushed in the style - which is where I think the problem comes from.

Is there some type of structure I need to specify in the BeautifulSoup function? I'm very lost here, so any help is much appreciated.

Fwiw I have installing the html2text module and had no luck installing on anaconda using `!conda config --append channels conda-forge` and `!conda install html2text`

Cheers

EDIT: ive figured it out. im a brainlet

```
request = urllib.request.Request('https://www.cftc.gov/sites/default/files/files/dea/cotarchives/2015/futures/financial_lf061615.htm')
htm = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
htm = htm.decode('windows-1252')
htm = htm.replace('\n','').replace('\r','')
htm = htm.split('</pre><pre>')

cleaned = []
for i in htm:
    i = BeautifulSoup(i,'html.parser' ).get_text()
    cleaned.append(i)

with open('trouble.txt','w') as f:
    for line in cleaned:
        f.write('%s\n' % line)
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific - what's an exact example of the output you're seeing that is different than what you expect?  And what are you doing with `BeautifulSoup` after you `get_text()`?  In other words, what's the final operation you need to execute on these data?

Comment: @andrew_reece  When you open the 2nd link you see a different structure to what is output through soup.get_text() in the first piece of code

Comment: Please see the guidelines for how to create a [mcve].  You'll get better answers, faster, if you can provide representative example data inline, in your post, rather than expecting others to do the legwork for you.  As is, it's not clear what your exact question is, nor what your exact desired output is.